# Duplicate lines in a query? (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, duplicates

Let me start by saying, i'm VERY new to SQL, coming from a Sysadmin background.

I'm trying to extract data based on a specific field being populated by a certain string. Let me show you my code, so you can probably laugh a little (some table names have been changed, also, ignore the dates, those are actually variables in the report, this is just an example) :)

```
SELECT 
    q2.Date AS Date,
    q2.[Language] AS [Language],
    q2.[User_Id] AS [UserName],
    q2.PhoneNumber AS [Phone],
    q1.Ending AS [Ending],
    q2.Score AS [Score]
FROM
    (SELECT         
         CA.ANI, DI.Disposition, CA.StartWrap, CA.NumTransfer
     FROM            
         [Gaetano].[dbo].[Call] CA 
     JOIN
         [Gaetano_Common].[dbo].[End] DI ON DI.Ending = CA.Ending
     WHERE           
         CA.NumTransfer = 'ESTA' 
         AND CA.EndDate BETWEEN '2019-09-24' AND '2019-09-25') q1
JOIN
    (SELECT        
         Pr.Date AS SurveyDate, 
         Pr.[Language] AS [Language], 
         [User_Id] AS [User], 
         acd.ANI AS [PhoneNumber], 
         Pr.Score AS [Score], 
     FROM            
         [dbo].[GaetanoPr] Pr 
     INNER JOIN
         [dbo].[ACDGaetano] acd ON acd.SeqNum = Pr.SeqNum 
                                AND NOT acd.Service_Id IS NULL 
                                AND NOT acd.[User_Id] IS NULL 
     WHERE
         Pr.Date BETWEEN '2019-09-24' AND '2019-09-25') q2 ON q2.PhoneNumber = q1.ANI
```

What I'm trying is that the only results I get are the ones that have the value 'ESTA' in the CA.NumTransfer column. I think the problem is when I join q1 and q2, as the result is always that a bunch of rows appear duplicated.

Comment: Yes - if there is two of the same phone number in q2, and that matches just one phone number in q1, you get two rows. To troubleshoot, pick just one set of your duplicate rows and inspect them individually from q1 and q2. The problem usually always boils down to: they aren't actually duplicate, there are different values in some fields, so decide if you want to ignore those fields or pick an arbitrary value

Comment: I think i will add another condition to the query besides 

q2 ON q2.PhoneNumber = q1.ANI


As you are correct, there are more rows that share that specific number, but not others.

I'll see how it goes!

Comment: Seems like you should be able to do this with a single query and an extra join instead of the subqueries which makes this more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: When i tried using a single query, the whole thing slowed to a crawl, but again, that's probably my inexperience with SQL.